# Is there a non constant bounded $C^\infty$ real function with infinity zeros in bounded interval $I$? But also non constant in any subinterval of $I$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, roots

> Is there a non constant bounded $C^\infty$ real function with infinity zeros in bounded interval $I$? But also non-constant in any subinterval of $I?$

I'm looking for some function like $x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ in $[-1,1]$, it has infinity zeros but it's not $C^\infty$.

I was wondering if this is possible or I have to prove such a function doesn't exist.

Comment: Multiply by something like $\exp(-1/x^2)$ instead of $x^2$ to smooth it out to all orders.

Comment: Yes, definitely $$\begin{cases}e^{-1/x^2}\sin(1/x)&x\neq 0\\0&x=0\end{cases}$$